# Sequelize can alter my database schemas?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to use sequelize to work with a `mysql` server.

However I dont want sequlelize touch/alter the mysql schemas I have because its a production server.

Is it:

```
sequelize.sync({ force: false })
```

enough for this?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any modification than just don't call `sync` at all. Calling sync without the force flag or with the force flag set to false will try to create databases. The creation will be skipped though if the table already exists.